# persist arabic diacritics data

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jakarta-ee

I want to insert arabic data that contains diacritics in my database but I got 
[this exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AnpX7.png)
I have already added this to the my.ini file

```
[client] default-character-set = utf8mb4 
[mysql]
default-character-set = utf8mb4
[mysqld]
character-set-client-handshake = FALSE
character-set-server = utf8mb4
collation-server = utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

and I also added this to my hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<property name="hibernate.connection.properties">useUnicode=yes;
characterEncoding=utf8;
</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.useUnicode">true</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.characterEncoding">utf-8</property>
```

but in vain

Answer (score 0):

In my case. I used to set the coding to utf-8. my.ini file has the following config

```
[client]
default-character-set = utf8

[mysql]
default-character-set = utf8

[mysqld]
character-set-server = utf8
collation-server = utf8_unicode_ci
```

I use the following url

```
 jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test?useUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=utf8&useSSL=false
```

cloud work fine.

Comment: I am in the window environment, I rename the my-default.ini to my.ini. and write the config above.

Comment: em....also execute command SET NAMES 'utf8';
SET CHARACTER SET utf8; in the mysql

Comment: I don't think the problem is mysql  because I tried manually inserting something in arabic and it worked , the problem is hibernate

Comment: I think your project coding may have some problem,before you insert the data to the database your data is already garbled.If you use maven manage your programe, you can set the coding in the pom.xml.for example set uat-8, add the  <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>. in the  <properties>.